# Asymptotic equality of $\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n(1-x)^n) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, asymptotics, legendre-polynomials

Consider the Shifted Legendre Polynomial $$\tilde P_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n(1-x)^n) $$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$

**Question:** What is the asymptotic equality of $\tilde P_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ where $0<x<1$?

By Rodrigues' formula for Legendre Polynomial $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)$$ then we have $\tilde P_n(x)=P_n(1-2x)$.

We have [in this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536211/asymptotic-expansion-of-legendre-polynomial) the following integral representation of $P_n(x)$ $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\cos(\theta))^n d\theta $$

and as $n\to \infty$,

$$P_n(x) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\frac{(x+(x^2-1)^{1/2})^{n+1/2}}{(x^2-1)^{1/4}}$$
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That asymptotics for $P_n(x)$ is for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $0<x<1$ there is a unique $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $x=\sin^2 \alpha$. Then
$$
\widetilde P_n ( \sin ^2 \alpha ) = P_n (1 - 2\sin ^2 \alpha ) = P_n (\cos (2\alpha )).
$$
Hence by the [Wikipedia results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Asymptotics),
$$
\widetilde P_n (\sin ^2 \alpha ) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{{\pi n\sin (2\alpha )}}} \cos \left( {(2n + 1)\alpha  - \tfrac{\pi }{4}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\widetilde P_n (\sin ^2 \alpha ) = \sqrt {\frac{{2\alpha }}{{\sin (2\alpha )}}} J_0 ((2n + 1)\alpha ) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. The latter one has a removable singularity at $\alpha=0$, so allows $x=0$ as well.

Comment: ($+1$). Thanks a lot for the elegant answer. Please write the result in terma of $x$. Also can we simplify a bit? What is $J_0$?

Comment: Just replace $\alpha$ by $\operatorname{arcsin}(\sqrt x)$, you cannot make it much simpler than that, except $\sin (2\alpha ) = 2\sqrt {x(1 - x)}$. $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$ (as the Wikipedia page tells you).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But we also have the condition $0<x<1$. Won't it be helpful?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am assuming here.

Comment: So we have the following asymptotic equality:$$
\widetilde P_n (\sin ^2 \alpha ) \sim \sqrt {\frac{2}{{\pi n\sin (2\alpha )}}} \cos \left( {(2n + 1)\alpha  - \tfrac{\pi }{4}} \right)
$$?

Comment: The problem with that is that the zeros of the two sides do not coincide, so taking the ratio does not work for all $\alpha$. So at zeros of the $\cos$ factor, the statement in my answer is that $\widetilde{P}_n(\sin^2\alpha) =\mathcal{O}(1/n^{3/2})$.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes you have answered. I have accepted your answer. Thanks